# No module named query on haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, pythonpath

I was using haystack on my Windows computer, but I realized I needed other modules for my django app that are easier to install on Linux, so I moved to my VirtualBox with Ubuntu. I installed everything with virtualenv in a venv folder. Basically my app uses haystack with a Whoosh backend.
On view.py, on the import lines, when I do `from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet` it throws a `No module named query` error. Any ideas what might be wrong? Here is the entire error. I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the Python path. I installed everything with pip on the virtual env.

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version:     1.4
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

No module named query

Exception Location:     /home/app/dj/venv/theme/../theme/views.py in <module>, line 10
Python Executable:  /home/app/dj/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/app/dj/venv/theme',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/app/dj/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I did a very dumb mistake. 
I used `pip install haystack` instead of `pip install django-haystack`.

Comment: Also a very very dumb mistake here, thanks for saving my life